How to recover a signer address with ECDSA.sol from Openzeppelin using a signature from ethers.js V6?
I'm basically trying to implement a whitelist system on my smart contract using ECDSA signature. I know we can do it with Merkle trees but i would like to be able to expand this whitelist as much as i want without paying fees for each addresses. I saw that Openzeppelin published two complementary libraries (ECDSA.sol and MessageHashUtils.sol) so I've decided to use them. Please note that I'm using hardhat for development and ethers.js version 6.13.3.
So, I first tried to create signatures with ethers.js, and tried to recover it to see if I could make it work. To achieve this, I wrote this code. Its purpose is to sign a message containing an address addr2.address with a signer represented by addr1 and then recover signer address addr1.address with the same message and the signature:
const [admin, addr1, addr2, addr3] = await ethers.getSigners();
const abiCoder = new ethers.AbiCoder();
const encodedAddress = await abiCoder.encode(
    ["address"],
    [addr2.address]
);
const messageHash = ethers.keccak256(encodedAddress);
const ethSignedMessageHash = ethers.hashMessage(messageHash);
const signature = await addr1.signMessage(ethSignedMessageHash);
const recoveredAddress = ethers.verifyMessage(
    ethSignedMessageHash,
    signature
);

console.log("Signature :", signature);
console.log("Recovered address : ", recoveredAddress);
console.log("Signer address : ", addr1.address)

Here's what I got :
Signature : 0x85ea0dfe1077f7f978c0be6ee202a5d851f09c0f699e870f34662ed14e8cd4305d2bb12a6ae9662a4c3f0363985666c1ac5014c90bae6fb9bfe77adbe93231be1c
Recovered address : 0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8
Signer address : 0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8

As you can see, recovered address and signer address are the same.
Then, I tried to implement the verification part in my smart contract, using ECDSA.sol and MessageHashUtils.sol. Here is my code (This code purpose is only to illustrate a minting function with a whitelist check):
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.25;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MessageHashUtils.sol";

contract test {
    using ECDSA for bytes32;
    using MessageHashUtils for bytes32;

    uint256 public supply;

    address public _SignerAddress = 0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8;

    function mint(bytes memory signature) external {
        require(_checkWhitelist(signature));
        supply++;
    }

    function _checkWhitelist(bytes memory signature) internal view returns (bool) {
        bytes32 hashedMessage = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender)).toEthSignedMessageHash();

        return hashedMessage.recover(signature) == _SignerAddress;
    }
}

I also wrote a test with ethers.js and chai:
it("Should increment supply from 0 to 1 if addr2 is whitelisted", async function{
  const [admin, addr1, addr2, addr3] = await ethers.getSigners();
  const abiCoder = new ethers.AbiCoder();
  const encodedAddress = await abiCoder.encode(
    ["address"],
    [addr2.address]
  );
  const messageHash = ethers.keccak256(encodedAddress);
  const ethSignedMessageHash = ethers.hashMessage(messageHash);
  const signature = await addr1.signMessage(ethSignedMessageHash);

  await ECDSATest.connect(addr2).mint(signature);
  expect(supply).to.equal(1);
}

Unfortunately, after hours of debugging, I still don't understand why this test is not getting passed.
Here's what I know for sure :

Both process (Off-chain and On-chain) Has to be exactly the same.

ethers.hashMessage() prefixes the message with MessagePrefix (i.e. "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n") and the decimal length of message and computes the keccak256 digest.

toEthSignedMessageHash returns the keccak256 digest of an EIP-191 signed data with version 0x45 (personal_sign messages). The digest is calculated by prefixing an arbitrary message with "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + len(message) and hashing the result.


Maybe ethers.hashMessage() and toEthSignedMessageHash() don't produce the same digest, or the same prefix or maybe I'm doing something wrong in my code. I feel like I've tried all I could but I need some advice here.
Thanks everyone.
Here are some links for documentation :

OpenZeppelin ECDSA doc
ethers.js hashMessage doc


You need to do a few changes off-chain i.e., in the signature generation using ethers in your script as well as on-chain i.e., in the signature verification in your contract.
ethers.hashMessage() and toEthSignedMessageHash() produce the same output, but the input that you're passing in ethers.hashMessage() should be converted to bytes array first.
Means, the output of ethers.hashMessage(ethers.getBytes(messageHash)) is same as the output of messageHash.toEthSignedMessageHash() .
And, in the contract, instead of abi.encodePacked, you've to use abi.encode while generating the hash.
Also, while recovering the signer on-chain, you've to consider the prefix "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32" and hash it together with the message hash. For combining the prefix, you've to use abi.encodePacked.
Here's the revised script:
const [admin, addr1, addr2, addr3] = await ethers.getSigners();
const abiCoder = new ethers.AbiCoder();
const encodedAddress = await abiCoder.encode(
    ["address"],
    [addr2.address]
);
const messageHash = ethers.keccak256(encodedAddress);
const ethSignedMessageHash = ethers.hashMessage(ethers.getBytes(messageHash));
const signature = await addr1.signMessage(ethers.getBytes(ethSignedMessageHash));
console.log(ethSignedMessageHash);
const recoveredAddress = ethers.verifyMessage(
    ethers.getBytes(ethSignedMessageHash),
    signature
);

console.log("Signature :", signature);
console.log("Recovered address : ", recoveredAddress);
console.log("Signer address : ", addr1.address);

And, here's the revised contract with some added functions using which you can cross-check the generated values at various steps:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.25;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MessageHashUtils.sol";

contract test {
    using ECDSA for bytes32;
    using MessageHashUtils for bytes32;

    uint256 public supply;

    address public _SignerAddress = 0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8;

    function mint(bytes memory signature) external {
        require(_checkWhitelist(signature));
        supply++;
    }

    function getABIEncodedMessage() external view returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encode(msg.sender));
    }

    function getEthSignedMessageHash() external view returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encode(msg.sender)).toEthSignedMessageHash();
    }

    function _checkWhitelist(bytes memory signature)
        internal
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        bytes32 hashedMessage = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(
                "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32",
                keccak256(abi.encode(msg.sender)).toEthSignedMessageHash()
            )
        );

        return hashedMessage.recover(signature) == _SignerAddress;
    }

    function recoverSigner(bytes memory signature)
        external
        view
        returns (address)
    {
        bytes32 hashedMessage = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(
                "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32",
                keccak256(abi.encode(msg.sender)).toEthSignedMessageHash()
            )
        );

        return hashedMessage.recover(signature);
    }
}

NOTE: Make sure to use the same signer (corresponding to addr1 that you've used to sign the hashed message in your script) to sign / call the mint() function.

Thanks for your solution, it works well. I just need to clarify one thing. I don't understand why, on-Chain, we still have to manually hardcode the prefix since the code of the method toEthSignedMessageHash() already prefix the digest you pass as parameter.
Source : https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/cryptography/MessageHashUtils.sol

It’s passing the prefix implicitly while hashing using toEthSignedMessageHash(). But, in the ECDSA.recover(), it isn’t considering the prefix, that’s why it’s needed to pass that explicitly.
